# get all the latest entries from table linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have two tables like below: (date format : mm/dd/yyyy)

Parameter master table:

```
   Id  Parameter
    1      ST
    2      GP
    3     Interest    
    4      CC
```

And Second TaxValue table :

```
Date     ParameterId   Value
1/1/2017    1          4
2/1/2017    1          4.5
1/15/2017   2          15
3/20/2017   2          20
3/21/2017   3          18
4/28/2017   3          20
1/1/2017    4          10
```

I want to write a linq query to get all the latest parameters values from the date specified.

Desired Result: (if I want to get latest entries for today)

```
Date     Parameter   Value
2/1/2017    ST          4.5
3/20/2017   GP          20
4/28/2017   Interest    20
1/1/2017    CC          10
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

User **`OrderByDescending`**

```
var result = from n in table
        group n by n.Value into g
        select g.OrderByDescending(t=>t.Date).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I actually tried above way but not able to resolve errors. I have edited my question .. please see if you can still help on actual scenario with join.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a join on the latest TaxValue record like this:

```
var qry = (from pm in parameterMaster

           from tax in taxValue.Where(t => t.ParameterId == pm.Id)
                               .OrderByDescending(t => t.Date)
                               .Take(1)
                               .DefaultIfEmpty()
           select new {
                date = tax.Date,
                parameter = pm.Name,
                value = tax.Value
           });

var results = qry.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query: (I tested it and it worked properly)

```
using (testEntities db = new testEntities())
            {               
                var res = from element in
                              (from p in db.Parameters
                               join t in db.TaxValues on p.Id equals t.ParameterId
                               select new { Date = t.Date, Parameter = p.Parameter1, Value = t.Value, ParameterId = t.ParameterId }).ToList()
                          group element by element.ParameterId
                              into groups
                              select groups.OrderBy(p => p.Value).Last();
            }
```

**Result**
[image: query]

Comment: @vivek Please upvote and accept this answer if it helps you, so people know this is the correct answer and helps them.